# SQL server databases are stucked in restoring state

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-administration, sql-server-2012

I have a single server in my SharePoint 2010 server farm. Today some of users complained about that some of Infopath forms can not be opened. When I checked the SOL Server Management Studio I saw that some of my databases are in *Restoring* state as you see in the image below!!!
[image]

Do you know any reason why this has happened and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run a `restore database` ? I think you did because it cannot happen on its own. Or maybe there is a scheduled task somewhere ?

But nevermind, it seems that your databases have not been brought up online after the restore process.

You can bring them online manually using `ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET ONLINE;`

To bring them up online automatically as part of the restore process, just use `WITH RECOVERY` option within your database `RESTORE` command.

Comment: Actually I haven't run ant script. I guess the backup tool that the network admin uses is the reason of this problem!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the option in Backup job under maintenance plan
2. Take the tail log backup and keep the database in Restoring state.
3. To Over Come,disable the above said option
   and run the following query for each affected Database
4. Restore database DB_NAME with recovery;